# Get user location only working from second time on

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

First: Sorry for the bad title. I don't know how to better describe my problem.

I have this this code in my Xcode project:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation = "PLACEHOLDER"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        currentLocation = String(locValue.latitude)
    }
    @IBAction func sendLocation() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print(currentLocation)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

This prints the user location when clicking on the UIButton.

This is working. But for some reason, when first time pressing the UIButton after restarting the app, it prints `PLACEHOLDER` instead of the location.

Means: When I start the app and click on the UIButton three times, I'm getting this in console:

```
PLACEHOLDER
56.153666216328625
56.153666216328625
```

instead of this:

```
56.153666216328625
56.153666216328625
56.153666216328625
```

I also tried to store as `UserDefaults` instead as `var`, but this results in the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that location updates are received asynchronously, so you're printing the value of `currentLocation` before a new location update would trigger the delegate call `locationManager(_:, didUpdateLocations)` and hence your `currentLocation` variable is printed before it would be updated. You need to print the value inside the delegate method to display the updated value.

Btw if you want to receive a single location update, you shouldn't use `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` right after each other, especially since you might actually stop updated before a single update would happen due to asynchronicity. You should be using `requestLocation` to receive a one-time location update. Moreover, you should be using the `locations` variable in the delegate call, not `manager.location`.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let coordinate = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }
    currentLocation = String(coordinate.latitude)
    print(currentLocation)
}

@IBAction func sendLocation() {
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}
```

Comment: I already tried `locationManager.requestLocation()` instead of start und stop, but this makes my app crash. Any idea why? I tried again with your code but it's still crashing with `locationManager.requestLocation()`.

Comment: I need to call `print(currentLocation)` from my IBAction. Is there a way to `return` `currentLocation`?

Comment: @David you should also make sure that the button triggering the `IBAction` is disable until location usage authorisation is granted, probably you have a crash due to requesting location before getting authorisation from the user. No, you can't return `currentLocation`, since the delegate method is called asynchronously. However, since the delegate method can only be called after the `IBAction` is triggered, you don't actually need to print from the `IBAction`, printing in the delegate method achieves the same result

Comment: Authorisation is not the problem. This is sure.

Comment: @David then you should edit your question with the crash reason, otherwise I'm out of ideas

Comment: 2 Years later same problem. I've tested 3 different ways, using requestLocation, using AppleMaps running in the background, even calling request location twice, waiting before doing anything- it always takes twice :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

Location updates are sent to you asynchronously so you can't print currentLocation right after calling startUpdatingLocation().

Just put the print inside the delegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    currentLocation = String(locValue.latitude)
    print(currentLocation) // print only after updating the location
}
```

and it should work